# Best way to deploy classic asp webapp with sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, asp-classic, hosting

I have a classic ASP front end which serves to collaboratively enter data into a sqlite database, meant to be used later in an android app. I need to deploy this ASP webapp onto an online server with sqlite odbc installed, because the only other option I know is to use my own computer as a server, and I don't think it would be a good idea to keep my fairly modest PC always on for 3 months or so.

The problem is, I can't find any server (preferably free) fitting these requirements.

Any ideas?

For example, is it possible to host just the sqlite file somewhere, and have the asp script (which I will then install on all the users' machines) access it remotely? I've looked around, and I've found a [solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20080206190515/http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/why-can-t-i-access-a-database-or-text-file-on-another-server.html) (for MS Access), but it involves changing user permissions on the server machine, which I won't be able to do.

Comment: Why dont you setup a free server on AWS EC2, with windows IIS7, and then you can install whatever ODBC drivers you want.  Its not going to be a beast, but it will get you a machine on the cheap that you have full control over.

Comment: That's actually a great Idea. However I've managed to find an easy way to convert my sqlite database into MS Access and make it work with my webapp. There are several free asp hosts that support MS Access. I just need to figure out an easy way to convert it back to sqlite when I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I came up with a good solution:

I imported my database into MS Access (from Access -> external data -> ODBC database -> follow the steps to choose your database). It works well with my ASP front-end after a few minor modifications.

I can now use any ASP hosting service as they all support MS Access.

When I'm done, I can convert it back to sqlite using this excellent program ([SQLite2009Pro](http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/) - it's actually free despite what the name may imply). I've tested the converted database with my android app and it works flawlessly.

Hope this helps anyone who's still stuck using ASP like me.